Same fedora system, same kernel, same driver and application. In one mmap works, in another one it fails
We have 2 identical CPU's HW , the difference only in BIOS. One has newer version.
Same Fedora kernel version, same driver and application.
On HW with new BIOS version application fails on 2 time when mmap been called.

Here is the function call:

Bellow dmesg dump when it fails.
Actual code:
base_ptr = (volatile void *) mmap(NULL, (size_t)size,
PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
MAP_SHARED, fd, (off_t)(pagesz * action));
The difference betwee 2 calls:
size = 16777216 , action = 0
size = 524288   , action = 1
pagesz = 4096 for both of them.
Need suggestion  how find why it fails with newer system.
Thanks in advance.

I forgot that i need reserve memory in kernel for this driver.
After reserving with gur2-mkconfig the error resolved.
Thanks,
